Login with Windows challenge goes in loop in ASP .Net app
I created an ASP.Net Core app with dotnet 8 for one identity service with individual user login
dotnet new mvc --auth Individual -o MyTestProject

Then I added code change for login with username and password and all worked fine.
Now I have to add Windows-based authentication also to this.
After making the changes in program.cs I added the following to my login page,
<form asp-controller="Identity" asp-action="LoginWithWindows" method="get">
    <button type="submit">Login with Windows</button>
</form>

then in my IdentityController class, I added
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult LoginWithWindows()
        {
            var redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home");
            // Challenge the user with Windows Authentication
            return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl }, NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

But the challenge window keeps asking for the username and password again and again even after entering the correct credentials.
I have updated the iisSettings like this
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:41772",
      "sslPort": 44356
    }
  }

So how to fix this never-ending loop of Sign-in challenge?
PS: When I created an app with dotnet new webapp --auth Windows the Windows authentication worked fine without any changes in IIS.


Install a Diff Comparison tool like BeyondCompare or SourceGear Diff and individually compare the difference between the working and non-working and let us know what they are?

Correct me if I'm wrong.
When we create a Windows auth project with dotnet new webapp --auth Windows,
the authentication occurs at the application level rather than in individual controller code.
So the authentication happens before the request reaches the controller level. Hence we can't compare code to see the diff.

Hmm, can you change the .AddNegotiate()  to have a cookie and use the default AuthenticationScheme, eg: .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {     options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";  // The login path as per your apps setup }) .AddNegotiate(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); also check chrome://settings/ that Automatic Logon with current username and password is enabled.

added like this
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {     options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // Default to Cookie Authentication     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // Default challenge to Windows Authentication }) .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {     options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Signin"; }) .AddNegotiate();
and can not update AddNegotiate(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) since it gives compilation error.
but the issue is same.

The two authentication methods differ completely, so your little manual changes won't bring the project from one to the other. That is also why a new project from scratch works flawlessly. Don't try to mix anything either, as often that makes things worse.

Do you mean you want to mix windows auth and asp.net core identity at same project? This is different things if you use two schema. Now you need clearly what is your requirement, to let the windows auth works for all the controller or let the identity works for all controller, or let both of them works for multiple controller.

@brando-zhang
I intend to create an identity service to run on a Windows machine, where users can log in with an allocated username or with Windows authentication. Currently, the controller organization does not matter.

@RenjuAshokan: as per your last comment, you want to allow users to login using with their usernames or windows username. Auto-logging windows users on a windows machine(via a middleware) seems like a viable option in your case. This would mean having a single schema with Windows User as one of the columns in AspNetUsers table. Is this what you are thinking of?

@SoftwareDveloper, let me clarify.
I want to create a server where users can log in with a pre-allocated username/password. Or there is a button to login with Windows  (similar to login with Google, or Facebook), on clicking this I want to do authentication with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate'.

Seems like negotiate would happen automatically.  (no need for "login with Windows" button...)  At that point they'd either be authenticated or not, but have no authorization yet.

After a few trial and error, I'm able to solve this issue.
Sharing the complete IdentityController in this gist.
The main changes are in the IdentityController.cs file, along with this I made changes in the program.cs also like below
// Configure Authentication to use both Windows Authentication (Negotiate) and Identity with Cookie Authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    // Do not set DefaultChallengeScheme here

})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Signin";
})
.AddNegotiate();

